# io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step ''.... are undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber

Been trying to learn/perform some automated testing using Selenium + JUnit + Cucumber and I've spent hours browsing through the internet trying to resolve this with no success. I've written my feature, steps and runner code and the 'glue' is mapped to the correct package too. However, I run into the topic error when I try to run my Runner.java file.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg6NE.png)

Feature file:

```
Feature: Admin login

Scenario: Logging into Fleet Portal
    Given user navigates to Fleet Portal
    When enter credentials
    Then user had logged
```

Runner file:

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.*;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Features"
        ,glue="Steps"
        )

public class TestRunner {}
```

Step file:

```
package Steps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

class App {
    private static final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public void myMethod(String flag) {
      System.out.println(flag);
    }
    @Given("user navigates to Fleet Portal")
    public void user_navigates_to_fleet_portal() {          
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }
    
    @When("enter credentials")
    public void enter_credentials() throws InterruptedException {                   
       
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
    }
    @Then("user had logged in successfully")
    public void user_had_logged_in_successfully() {
        myMethod("yes");
        throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
        }
}
```

I've tried to take JUnit out of the picture by simply running the feature file as a cucumber test but it still results in the same error, which is weird because the cucumber plugin confirms that the steps are mapped to the features -> [feature mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ZDb.png)

[POM file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI79C.png)

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the actual step definitions?

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong. You should remove the pending exceptions.

Comment: Also, you can try this project with a single passing and two undefined steps https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton